# Returning a module in RequireJS

Tags: requirejs

I'm refactoring a large javascript codebase to use RequireJS. Unfortunately, many of the files I'm dealing with are not object-oriented, and cannot return an object without significant modification. Is there a more efficient way to give 'dependent' modules access to the functions and variables contained in a module (without returning an object) ?

I have read about using the [exports](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#wiki-magic) syntax for defining modules, but it is very unclear whether that would be a valid solution for this situation.

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a defined module, the `exports` object is what gets exported from the module and passed to whatever module requires it.

Consider this:

```
define(["exports"], function(exports){
  exports.myCustomFunction = function(){};
  exports.myCustomObject = {};
  exports.myCustomVariable = true;
})
```

This module will place all the disparate functions and/or objects that you want made public onto the `exports` object.
At this point RequireJS will use that exports object to pass to a module that requires it:

```
require(["nameOfCustomModule|filename"], function(myCustomModule){
  //evaluates to true
  console.log(myCustomModule.myCustomVariable);
})
```

Here's a simple fiddle. Just bring up your console and you will see the value logged there.  http://jsfiddle.net/xeucv/

Hope this clears it up a bit!

Comment: This looks like a much more efficient alternative to making everything OO and returning an object. Thank you so much for clarifying and providing an example.